# get value of radio button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created radio button at runtime in server side

```
RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton();
button1.ID = question.Name + "_Radio1";
button1.Text = "Yes";

RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton();
button2.ID = question.Name + "_Radio2";
button2.Text = "No";
 if (question.IsDynamic)
 {
     button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return updateQuestions('" + button1.ID + "')");
  }
```

then at java script I try to get the value of radio button

```
  function updateQuestions(controlName) {


        var userAnswer;

        if (controlType == "RadioButton") {

            userAnswer = document.getElementById(controlName).innerHTML;
        }
```

and userAnswer is empty .how can I get the value of radio button???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `value`:

```
userAnswer = document.getElementById(controlName).value;
```

Also consider passing something besides id into the function.  If the value is what you are looking for, just pass the value.  Any of these approaches will work to pass the value directly to the function:

```
button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return updateQuestions('someValue')");
```

or

```
button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return updateQuestions(this.value)");
```

**Edit:** Also, if you aren't explicitly setting the value on the control server side, the value *is* empty string, so what you are seeing is correct.  Set the value when you create the control by going `button1.Value = "myValue";`.

```
RadioButton button1 = new RadioButton();
button1.ID = question.Name + "_Radio1";
button1.Text = "Yes";
button1.Attributes["value"] = "Yes";
```

Comment: .value also return empty string

Comment: @thabet - make sure you are setting a value server side.  Ie, `button1.Value = "SomeValue";`

Comment: @gilly3: how can I set value of radio button ,I setted text

Comment: @thabet - See the update to my answer.  `Text` is the label that is displayed.  The value of the control is not visible in the UI, it is the value sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: @gilly3: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @thabet - What!?  Ok, thank you ASP.Net!  Try adding the value via `Attributes`.  I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @gilly3 : now it run correct thanks---> button1.Attributes["value"]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
userAnswer = document.getElementById(controlName).value;
```

Comment: Where are you actually setting the value attribute of the element?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return updateQuestions('" + button1.ID + "')");`
to

```
button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return updateQuestions('" + button1.ClientID+ "')");
```

Comment: Actually, just this will do just fine: `"return updateQuestions(this)"`

Comment: @Sime Vidas. It will not. Because the function updateQuestions requires controlName string. Not the element.

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, I'd recommend passing the reference to the radio-button instead of the ID.